# Display foreign key info within Django Detail View Template

Tags: python, django

As the title says I have a detailed view that I'm presenting via Django templates. I have a foreign key that I'd also like to present within that detailed view and I just can't get it to work. I've tried everything, but all I get is the basic detailed view template with no foreign key info. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's what I've got so far:

**Models:**

```
class Cust(models.Model): #this is the main model
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    watchmanSlug = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
```

```
class Watchman(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Cust, on_delete=models.CASCADE,to_field='watchmanSlug', 
    related_name='watchman_group_slug')
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    computer_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    computer_url = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**Views**

```
class CustomerDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Cust
    template_name = 'cust/cust_detail.html'
    
    def get_context_data(self, ** kwargs):
        context = super(CustomerDetailView, self).get_context_data( ** kwargs)
        context['computer_name'] = Watchman.objects.all()
        
        return context
```

***Detail Template***

```
                     <tbody>
                        <ul>
                          {% for p in watchman_group_slug.all %}
                          <li>{{ watchman.computer_name }}</li>
                          {% endfor %}
                
                      </ul>
                      </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

You access the related `Watchman` objects with:

```
<tbody>
  <ul>
    {% for p in object.watchman_group_slug.all %}
      <li>{{ p.computer_name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</tbody>
```

so with `object.watchman_group_slug.all`, and with the `.computer_name` of `p`.

Comment: Holy crap, that was so fast. You're a wizard - thank you. - Also that worked.